# Concurrency embedded Java Database for simple Application

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

I am trying to build a simple GUI in which you can write some Integers. These Integers are supposed to be written into a Database, which I am looking for.

So far so good. The data in the Database should then be used for another stand-alone application, which already exists.

I tried it with SQLite already but I received a lot of "Database locked" Errors. I searched Google. The key answer I often read about was to switch to a database which supports concurrent processes.

I went further on and had a look at H2 and HSQLDB. Both of them seem to be legit but much more complicated.

**So I wonder:**

I would like to have the GUI to be portable in a .jar file (or a folder only) combined with the Database, so when I switch computers I do not have to install the DB in a certain folder like the home-directory or something. With SQLite all you do is this:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
```

As you can see, no Path-infortmation is necessary. How can I do this with H2 or HSQLDB?

I am really looking forward to your suggestions. But only open source please.

Kindest regards and thank you very much!

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With H2 and HSQLDB you can do the same.

With H2, a database URL of the form `jdbc:h2:test` will create a file called `test.h2.db` in the current working directory of your application. If this is what you want, then that's fine. Please note I usually don't suggest to do that, because many people run into the problem that they sometimes start the application in a different directory (which will then create a new database). Because of that, I suggest to use `jdbc:h2:~/test`, which means the database file is stored relative to the current user home directory.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Please correct me if I am wrong: Does this mean that if have an executable .jar-file and run this on an other computer -> on the first run the database will be stored at "~/test"?

Comment: Yes, with the database URL `jdbc:h2:~/test`, the database file will be stored in the current user home directory, under the name `test.h2.db`. If such a database file already exists, it is re-used of course.

Answer (score 0):

Handling the creation of an embedded db file should not be a big issue - but if you really dislike this stick with SQLite: it should handle concurrency well enough for basic usage - 'database locked' sounds more like an application level problem

Comment: Thank you Mark. I will definitely give it a try and take closer look at possible open connections in my application. I would love to go on with SQLite but different posts found by google made think to switch to another database. Thanks!